# com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.IllegalMutationException in DoFn

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I wrote a `DoFn<String, Set<SectionBodyRecord>>` that outputs a Set.
When I execute my pipeline I get the exception

```
Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.IllegalMutationException: DoFn UnmarshalGcsPath mutated value
    [SectionBodyRecord{txId='3UR93528NX413902J'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='15N97640P5806660M'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='7TG473112Y9407154'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='9A1906561E887050P'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='4FP63718R4365381L'}]
    after it was output (new value was
    [SectionBodyRecord{txId='9A1906561E887050P'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='7TG473112Y9407154'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='3UR93528NX413902J'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='4FP63718R4365381L'},
    SectionBodyRecord{txId='15N97640P5806660M'}]).
    Values must not be mutated in any way after being output.
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$ImmutabilityCheckingOutputManager.verifyOutputUnmodified(ParDo.java:1344)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$ImmutabilityCheckingOutputManager.output(ParDo.java:1306)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:450)
        at my.tests.pipelines.CsvToDatastore$UnmarshalGcsPath.processElement(CsvToDatastore.java:185)
```

I do not understand where the problem could be. Moreover, I have tried with

```
ImmutableSet<SectionBodyRecord> irecs = ImmutableSet.copyOf(records);
c.output(irecs);
```

but the problem remains.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code of UnmarshalGcsPath. Could you post it?

Comment: What kind of `Set` representation is being used? How is equality defined for both the `Set` and the `SectionBodyRecord`? Based on the error, it looks like the sets are equivalent (though they have a different) which should still cause the sets to be treated as equal. Are `SectionBodyRecord`s treated as equal if they have equal `txId` values?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use a `HashSet` in the background, and you haven't (re)implemented a `hashCode()` function for `SectionBodyRecord` - at least that was my problem.

You can either define `hashCode()` like `int hashCode() { return txId.hashCode(); }`, or use a `TreeSet` instead and implement the `Comparable<SectionBodyRecord>` interface.

The reason why you get the error is that the data contained in the set changes positions every time you create the set, because there is no deterministic way to nail down the order (in case of `TreeSet`) or position (in case of `HashSet`) of your `SectionBodyRecord` elements.